# jqGrid getRowData doesn't return the current set of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

i'm implementing the copy functionality in jqGrid in inline edit mode. On clicking the copy icon for a row the contents of the row will be added as new row. On clicking copy the new row gets created but the copied data in cell is not the current data that is entered in the row.

getRowData method returns row value of previous state. The updated data is returned only after reloadGrid function is invoked.

I get the data from the row using the below code and then reset the required data and again add it as a new row using addRowData method.

```
var dataFromTheRow = $(_gridID).jqGrid('getRowData', _rowid);
// Before calling addRowData dataFromTheRow is updated.
$(_gridID).jqGrid('addRowData',newId,dataFromTheRow, "after", _rowid);
```

When I directly try to get the value using document.getElementById its returning the current value but the getRowData function isn't.

Any idea why the getRowData function is not returning the current value from the DOM instantly and any inputs to get over this issue will be highly helpful?

jqGrid:  4.3.2, 
Grid Data Type: JSON

Comment: getRowData is not compatible with editing modes. This is a well know feature. Please look into the [docs - search for getRowData here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods)

Comment: @TonyTomov thanks for pointing to the link. is there any other way to achieve my use case?

Comment: if you make a demo with data and steps to reproduce the problem, then I think I can help.